# How to replace wildcharacter in CSV

Tags: excel, csv, replace

I have below string in csv files

`Part Number WP1166496 (AP6005317) replaces 1166496, 1156976.`

Expected Output - 
`Part Number WP1166496 replaces 1166496, 1156976.`

I want to replace (AP6005317) this with blanks.

As there are many rows with different values.

So how can I replace this string with brackets to blanks value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to achieve this exactly in `Microsoft Excel`.

If you look for `find and replace` feature, most probably you can see option to replace with `regular expressions`.

Use `regular expression` option and replace `\(.*\)` with (simple space). This will solve your problem.

**Note :** This is tested and verified in `LibreOffice Calc`.

Comment: How to replaces `Part Number WP1166496 replaces` to `Part Number cell Value replaces` other cell value